# while all element are not zero in an array Fortran

Tags: fortran, do-while

I'm trying to use a loop that will run until all element of two array are 0 :

I was thinking doing :

```
DO WHILE(ALL(QueueST/=0) .AND. ALL(QueuePT/=0))
!here things to do 
END DO
```

Is that correct ? is there a better way ? 
What about :

```
DO    
IF(ALL(QueueST/=0) .AND. ALL(QueuePT/=0))THEN
  EXIT
END IF 
    !here things to do 
END DO
```

is it different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not correct. In the do while use

```
 DO WHILE(ALL(QueueST/=0) .OR. ALL(QueuePT/=0))
```

and in the second form

```
IF(ALL(QueueST==0) .AND. ALL(QueuePT==0)) EXIT
```

The two conditionals should be opposite to each other in those two versions.

Comment: And I think should also change `ALL` to `ANY` in the `while` loop ?

Comment: `do while( .not. (ALL(QueueST==0) .AND. ALL(QueuePT==0)))` might be best for readability